# Diablo 3 and Torment difficulty levels, "New legendary items become available at level 70"?

Tags: diablo-iii

When choosing difficulty, all the Torment difficulty settings have this statement:

> New legendary items become available at level 70

Does this mean that for, say, Torment VI, there are legendary items that can drop that will never, ever, drop on lower difficulties?

The torment difficulties, that all have this statement, each have their own separate loot table that builds on the previous one, but adds specific items that can only be obtained on that level and above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain items that have been added to the game as it's been developed were never added for levels lower than 70. That's why you see that statement.

There are also legendaries that ONLY drop in Torment difficulties. As long as you are level 70 and playing on Torment 1, you will have a chance at getting ALL legendary drops.

The only benefit on going to a higher Torment level is a greater chance of a legendary dropping. (and more exp in general)

Comment: OK, so that part of the rewards is "this is what you will get", it doesn't mean " ... compared to the previous torment".

Comment: I was actually both hoping and not hoping it was the way I described, I've been trying for a week and a half now to get a Ring of Royal Grandeur and was hoping the explanation was something simple as "You must play on Torment X to be able to get it", but with your answer it just turns out I'm just unlucky :)

Comment: If you're looking for a Ring of Royal Grandeur...you can only get it from an Act 1 Cache Drop. You have to complete all of the bounties in Act 1 and then talk to Tyreal to complete the bounty. You won't get it from a monster drop at all.